# iOS subscription promotional offers without a server

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, receipt-validation, in-app-purchase-receipt

I'm new to the topic of iOS auto renewable subscriptions, and I'm trying to understand 2 things:

1. Is it possible to work with subscriptions without a server? If my only goal for now is simply to understand if the subscription is active or not.
2. Is it possible to use [promotional offers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_promotional_offers_in_your_app) without a server?

In Apple docs they always mention a server-side component for receipt validation, but, at the same time, I see libraries like [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit), which have [methods for subscription validation](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/wiki/Verify-Subscription). So, #1 seems possible. But then maybe #2 is possible, too?

I suspect, without server-side validation malicious users may be able to fake a subscription somehow, but is that all I'd need to worry about?